# Java URL counter is not working

Tags: java, regex, url

I'm trying to count the number of URLs in any given Java string:

```
String test = "Hello World!";
String urlRegex = "<\\b(https?|ftp|file)://[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]>";
pattern = Pattern.compile(urlRegex);
matcher = pattern.matcher(test);
numUrls = matcher.groupCount();
System.err.println("numUrls = " + numUrls);
```

I am surprised to see that `numUrls` is not zero. Any ideas as to why? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to use matcher.find(), there's always one group.

Comment: What if there are 6 URLs in the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the javadoc for [`Matcher#groupCount()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#groupCount())

> Returns the number of capturing groups in this matcher's pattern.

Your pattern has one group `...(https?|ftp|file)...` so it returns 1.

Comment: Hmmm good catch and +1 - so what do I need to use instead of `groupCount`?

Comment: Im trying to count the number of URLs in a Java string.

Comment: Loop on `find()` and use your own counter.

Comment: So like `while(matcher.find()) numUrls++;`?