# Java URL regex not matching

Tags: java, regex, string, url

I am trying to count the number of URLs in a Java string:

```
String test = "This http://example.com is a sentence https://secure.whatever.org that contains 2 URLs.";
String urlRegex = "<\\b(https?|ftp|file)://[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]>";
int numUrls = 0;
pattern = Pattern.compile(urlRegex);
matcher = pattern.matcher(test);
while(matcher.find())
    numUrls++;
System.err.println("numUrls = " + numUrls);
```

When I run this it tells me I have zero (not 2) URLs in the string. Any ideas as to why? Thanks in advance!

Comment: what are the `<` and `>` doing.  looks like duplicated delimnators

Comment: I am just curious, why you ask questions from different accounts Mike: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15507679/1393766? Afraid of duplicate close? :)

Comment: @Pshemo - DirtyMike is my twin brother. We're working on a project together and only have access to 1 PC with internet access.  He asks his questions as DirtyMike, I ask my questions as TicketMonster. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `<` and `>` characters in `urlRegex` are causing a mismatch between your pattern and your input `test` `String`. Removing them will yield a `numUrls` value of `2` as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
        String data = "This http://example.com is a sentence https://secure.whatever.org that contains 2 URLs.";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[hH][tT]{2}[Pp][sS]?://(\\w+(\\.\\w+?)?)+");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(data);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
```

Hopefully it will work.

Comment: If you want to make regex case insensitive then just compile it as `Pattern.compile("some pattern",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)`, or add `(?i)` at start of regex: `Pattern.compile("(?i)some pattern")`.

Comment: @Pshemo : Thanks for the information. I had used Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE earlier but did not know about (?i). Thanks once again. :-)